# Unable to use session variables in 000webhost

Tags: php, session, session-variables, session-cookies, shared-hosting

I have a simple methodology to my page. Log in the user and if the credentails matched, the user is given a session variable “id” which is linked to the database to get info about the user. The thing was running fine on my “localhost” but it isn’t running here.
I run:

```
<?php
  if(isset($_SESSION["user"])){
   echo "the session variable is here!";
   //redirect to another page --probably dashboard or something like that-- 
  }
```

But when I run the page and I visit to the `"Secure"` button and see in the cookies section, the session is there but the string isn't print. I tried changing it to:

```
?>
<script>
alert("The session variable exists");
</script>
 <?php
```

But nothing gets `alerted!`
 I tried accessing the `.htaccess` file and adding one line that says: `php_flag session.auto_start on`
 but it doesn't work. So, what should I do?

**NOTE: It is to mention that I have `session_start()` and I haven't made those beginner mistakes.**

Comment: You're saying a session which is set over HTTP seems not to exist over HTTPS (even if the cookie is correctly returned to the server)? Sounds like the host may be running HTTP and HTTPS servers separately, and they're not sharing a common session store…?

Comment: @deceze so, what should I do? The solution???

Comment: You should inquire with the host about this.

Comment: I tried in the forum but the forum didn't seem to be helpful!